# Reflection Help - Set properties on object based on another object

Tags: c#, reflection, oop

I could use a bit of relection help. I am passing an object into the constructor of another object. I need to loop through the parameter's properties and set the new objects properties based on it. Most, but not all, of the params properties exist in the new object.

I have this so far, the basic skeleton.

```
  public DisabilityPaymentAddEntity(DisabilityPaymentPreDisplayEntity preDisplay)
  {
      Init(preDisplay);
  }

  private void Init(DisabilityPaymentPreDisplayEntity display)
  {
       //need some type of loop using reflection here
  }
```

In the 'Init' method, I need to loop through 'display's properties and set any of 'DisabilityPaymentAddEntity' properties of the same name to values in the preDisplay.

Can anyone give me a clue what I need to do? I am sure I need to use PropertyInfo etc..

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: Can you explain further why you need to use reflection? Actually, this sounds like a job for Automapper : http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper

Comment: HI Jay, Im going to give this a try. Is it fairly easy to use? I downloaded the samples and will check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Wow that Automapper worked like a champ!!! One question tho, where do I create the Map? In the examples I see online they suggest global.asax. I try to keep thing neat and tidy, and I will be using this DLL outside of my web application. Where do I set up a map inside a class library? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this I think

```
Type target = typeof(DisabilityPaymentAddEntity);
foreach(PropertyInfo pi in display.GetType().GetProperties())
{
     PropertyInfo targetProp = target.GetProperty(pi.Name);
     if(targetProp!=null)
     {
        targetProp.SetValue(this, pi.GetValue(display, null), null);
     }
}
```